# calculating reliability of measurements

Tags: statistics, average, variance

I have many measurements of age of the same person. Let's say:

```
[23 25 32 23 25]
```

I would like to output a single value and a reliability score of this value. The single value can be the average.

Reliability, I don't know well how to calculate it. The value should be between 0 and 1, where 1 means all ages are equal and a very unreliable measurement should be near 0.

Probably the variance should be used here, but it's not clear to me how to normalize it between 0 and 1 in a meaningful way (1/(x+1) is not much meaningful :)).

Comment: if one of the answers helped, please consider selecting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets community know the answer worked and the issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume some probability distribution (or determine what probability distribution your data fits most accurately). A good choice is a normal distribution, which for discrete data requires a continuity correction. See example here: http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/pdfc-normaldisc.htm

In your example, your reliability score for the average age of 26 (25.6 rounded to nearest integer), is simply the probability that X falls in the range (25.5, 26.5).

Comment: I don't need the probability of an age given an age distribution. I need to know how much robust is the average. For example if the average comes from values like 24,23,25,80,50, then it is not robust. In another terms, I can't trust this value.

Comment: Trust is represented by statisticians as confidence intervals, and that involves probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for assessing reliability (or internal consistency) is to use Cronbach's alpha. I guess most statistics software has this method built-in.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha